# Issue passing data from API

Tags: ios, api, serialization, swift2

This code is from the locations tableView view controller, where the locations are serialized from a Four Square API and I grab the data, passing it back the view controller where I create an event. The data is serialized correctly, populating the tableView and all, so I won't bother posting that for now, just the segue method to pass the data.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

    let item = self.responseItems![indexPath!.row]

    var eventVC = CreateEventViewController()

    if segue.identifier == "pushBackToEventVC" {

        if let venue = item["venue"] as? NSDictionary {

            let locationString = venue["name"] as! String
            let location = venue["location"]

            //get lat/long strings

            print(location)

            eventVC.updateWithLocation(locationString)
            eventVC.updateWithGeoPoint(PFGeoPoint(latitude: locationLatitude, longitude: locationLongitude))

        }

        eventVC = segue.destinationViewController as! CreateEventViewController

        //pass location coordinates 
    }

//the rest of the segue method 

}
```

The update methods in the crete event view controller, when I put a breakpoint on these methods I can see the data has been passed correctly, and the location (a PFGeoPoint) works okay but the locationString (a string) throws a "Bad instruction error" although it does print it correctly to the console

```
func updateWithLocation(locationString: String) {

    print(locationString)
    self.locationLabel.text = locationString
}

func updateWithGeoPoint(venueLocation: PFGeoPoint) {

//        print(venueLocation)
    self.event?.location = venueLocation
    self.eventLocation = venueLocation
    print(self.eventLocation)
}
```

Any ideas? It's basically working but won't update the label with the string although I can see it's been passed correctly. Thanks for the help as always.

Comment: Why don't you create a class variable and assign the location to that?

Comment: That's what I did before this but I got the same error

Comment: the issue is likely the way you are setting up the destination controller. use something like this,

let detailViewController = ((segue.destinationViewController) as! CreateEventViewController)

Comment: and you should map the parameters to the object you get out from that syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this code block instead,

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "pushBackToEventVC") {

        let detailViewController = ((segue.destinationViewController) as! CreateEventViewController)
        let indexPath = self.tableView!.indexPathForSelectedRow!

        detailViewController.locationString = venue["location"]
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you, I had to put the segue.destinationViewController before the rest of the code, that's what did it.